# Multithreading in WPF+WCF+Prism application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, prism

I am starting a project - client WPF application that communicates over WCF WebSockets with some service. I am using Prism framework as well.
I am wondering, which way is the proper way to implement multithreading (i need to keep UI responsive):

1. Use the service async methods along with the await.
2. Manually create a new thread, that will be responsible for client-service communication.

Sth like this:

```
Thread thread =new Thread(NewClientConnection);

thread.Start(some_arguments);
```

I am new to WPF/Prism and I fear that, I can have some issues in Prism, when modules are in different threads, don't know if this the right way. What do you think?

Comment: There's really no need these days to manage your own threads in UI applications. You're opening yourself up to a world of hurt with thread synchronization and marshaling UI updates to the dispatcher thread. Here's a similar answer with some good advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129182/wpf-wcf-async-service-call-and-synchronizationcontext

Comment: That's what I thought. So you are saying, that  first option is the correct one right? I won't block UI, because for every service method e.x GetLogins() the WCF generates itself GetLoginsAsync() that i can use.

Comment: You need an awaitable task in order to await it.  Something ended in async is usually such a thing. This is purely a naming convention though.

Comment: That's right - WCF can generate async versions of your service interface methods in the client proxy, but even synchronous calls can be fairly painlessly marshaled to a thread pool as a task, without you needing to create and manage your own threads. Threads are expensive.

Comment: In a desktop app, it rarely matters that creating a separate thread is processor expensive. What is much more significant is that using async await is easier to code. You just await your call result into a variable and then your next line of code can automatically use that variable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put any part of the ui in a non ui thread, because that will not work.  Otherwise, you can put services and stuff on separate threads if you must but that isn't usually necessary. 
Use async await.
Personally, I would go with wep api rather than wcf if I had the option. Maybe you don't.
If you're new to wpf then I suggest you think twice about using PRISM.  It has a lot of functionality in there and is very complicated.  Most applications do not need all that though.

PRISM is pretty tricky to work with.  In my experience, even with dynamically built UI it was largely just adding complex overhead to our projects.  If they want to essentially define different regions and place things in them then you don't absolutely need prism anyhow. You can build ui with xamlreader.parse to give 1,2,3 or whatever contentcontrols they want in a view and then set the content of each to a control.

WCF hasn't been deprecated, it's just the web api is simpler to use. If it does what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for additional info. About Prism: I wanted to give it a try. It wil simplify implementing MVVM pattern. Furthermore in my application i need to dynamically create cusom user controls (user opens settings tab from mainwindow, chooses with custom controls he wants to see in MainWindow, where he want to placed them, how he wants to customize them etc. About Web Api, why do you think it will be better? I need simple communication over WebSockets, so i dont think it would make a huge difference.WCF is still legit i think Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, I get it. But from what I have heard PRISM is a "lightweight" frameworkso is it a bad idea to use it in some areas, where it actually  makes things simple (mvvm pattern, prism properties) and for other stuff when things will get really complicated just don't use it?

Comment: PRISM is a massive heavyweight framework. There is a cut down nugget version which just gives you a couple of things but MVVMLight is a better option than that. In my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Make the service calls async on the client side.

> issues in Prism, when modules are in different threads

A module in the Prism context is basically a definition of services implementing interfaces. It lives only to have it's `Initialize` method called, then it dies.